# How to plot different categories of the same series

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Sorry if this has been asked before, but i couldn't find it anywhere. I want to plot different categories of the same series on different axis', as one category has signifigantly higher values than the rest.

when i try to create a graph, this is what I get [image: this],

so i want to have the "number bought" category plotted along a secondary axis, but when i try to set the axis, i can only select series,
 shown here [image: this].

is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

After creating your chart, right click on one of the columns and click on `Format Data Series` in the right-click menu.

You should then see the option `Plot Series on Secondary Axis`.

---

For your particular data set, I would also suggest right-clicking anywhere on the chart and clicking `Select Data`, and removing the series that are automatically generated by Excel.

Then, add a series for your `dollars` data, add a separate series for your `number bought` data, and select your years for the horizontal axis labels.